# How to get working with hirefire for delayed_job in rails 3 in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, hirefire

I am developing an app with rails 3 using delayed_jobs. I'm using Hirefire to scale up and down workers as and when needed. How can I get hirefire working in my development environment, to test it is working as it is intended to.

Then how should I also configure it so it also works in my production environment in Heroku Cedar stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is to set the `environment` to `:local`. By default it is set to `:noop` which does nothing. To do this, create a initializer for hirefire at `Rails.root/config/initializers/hirefire.rb`. In the initializer, add the following

```
HireFire.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.production?
    config.environment = :heroku
   else
    config.environment = :local
  end
  # add any other configuration you want here
end
```